# Generate union type using array type indices

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
type DefaultTheme = {
  name: 'default';
  colors: [string, string, string];
};

type CustomTheme = {
  name: 'custom';
  colors: [string, string, string, string, string];
};

type DefaultColor = ???; // 'default-1' | 'default-2' | 'default-3';

type CustomColor = ???; // 'custom-1' | 'custom-2' | 'custom-3' | 'custom-4' | 'custom-5';
```

The question is whether it's possible to use the length of the `colors` array to create a mapped union type as in the given example.

The example is simplified for (hopefully) clarity, but in full there is a generic type `Theme` that takes `name` and `length` arguments and uses `length` to generate a tuple of fixed number of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified @Aleksey L.'s solution a bit and took a different approach:

```
type Indices<T> = keyof T & `${number}`;
type Indices1<T extends [...any]> = Exclude<Indices<[...T, any]>, '0'>

type N_Test = Indices1<[string, string, string]> // '1' | '2' | '3'
type P_Test = `Test-${N_Test}`; // "Test-1" | "Test-2" | "Test-3"
```

Main differences:

- No use of ad-hoc mapped types `{ [key in ...]: ... }`
- No recursive types (like in @kaja3's answer).
- No conditional types `X extends Y ? ... : ...` (`Exclude` uses this internally, but it is a nice abstraction)

Applied to the example:

```
type DefaultTheme = {
  name: 'default';
  colors: [string, string, string];
};

type CustomTheme = {
  name: 'custom';
  colors: [string, string, string, string, string];
};

type WithPrefix<T extends {name: string, colors: string[]}> = `${T['name']}-${Indices1<T['colors']>}`;

type DefaultColor = WithPrefix<DefaultTheme>; // 'default-1' | 'default-2' | 'default-3';
type CustomColor = WithPrefix<CustomTheme>; // 'custom-1' | 'custom-2' | 'custom-3' | 'custom-4' | 'custom-5';
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Right, I always forget that union can be used straight in the template literal

Comment: Just small correction - no recursive types in original solution as well. And `Exclude` is actually a wrapper around conditional type . The main difference here is a neat numeric keys extraction with "keyof T & ``${number}``"

Comment: Thanks, I was referring to kaja3's answer with that point :) I agree with Exclude, but I think it is a cleaner way to use the named library type instead of a language construct because it may be easier to google :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the evil  (some explanations in code comments):

```
// Pick only positive number strings
type Positive<N> = N extends `${number}` ? N extends "0" ? never : N : never

// Produce union of possible array indexes (starting from 1)
type IndexFrom1<T extends Array<any>> = keyof { [K in keyof [null, ...T] as Positive<K>]: any }

type WithPrefix<T extends Array<any>, Prefix extends string, Value = IndexFrom1<T>> =
  Value extends string ? `${Prefix}-${Value}` : never

type N_Test = IndexFrom1<[string, string, string]> // "1" | "2" | "3"
type P_Test = WithPrefix<[string, string, string], 'Test'> // "Test-1" | "Test-2" | "Test-3"
```

Now applying `WithPrefix` util to your examples:

```
type DefaultTheme = {
  name: 'default';
  colors: [string, string, string];
};

type CustomTheme = {
  name: 'custom';
  colors: [string, string, string, string, string];
};

type DefaultColor = WithPrefix<DefaultTheme["colors"], DefaultTheme["name"]>; // 'default-1' | 'default-2' | 'default-3';

type CustomColor = WithPrefix<CustomTheme["colors"], CustomTheme["name"]>; // 'custom-1' | 'custom-2' | 'custom-3' | 'custom-4' | 'custom-5';
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUEsGMGtQPYDsA2BPUAHBBnSAXSANwFNQkBXAWwCMSAnUHfeyJAcxwFgAofNTGXC4CxEgB4AcgD5QAXlCTQJAB74SSACY5QAAwAkAb0q0GAX12gA-IuVqN20ACIADE+vkSpRgC5bfpC8GXl4QCHoETQpoMgokSGREADMsXDwaFDIAQ3p6LIw2TVUSHQAKZhzCDlAkiKpQAEYASl5+QVAASS1VADE6hvEAFTt1LR0AQVz88SykNGlZBVgSNAQUw1AAbQBpUDZQZdWUzcoUFAAaUAA6G8GAXSydYTxCUnFt6Tu-WYwzEL4BGQAOoEAAW4HoJCSkBUQxGDgmUzQMzm0kuEKhMPhYyYLDY7EuADUsigKGQFF0iio+ggqANBgt5LxQKBiaSyKpRo5mKxqjYDIYMdCVGYALRGNlkiygAJBej-NpkSQAfUGJXw8k63Wp-XEmx5+MuBo4RrxHDusjCTga7gAPs4AEx25wAZicrUBEFV6s1IPw4Mhwr1xoJuN5oZDd0uAHI1cxo5awE44-hRTbQPbk+rRU6M84U6K3QrPQARKFZCgofCDUEkKjk0CGZnkLL1vzRopJCtV6MAbmb0AQKAQ9Bwfn1Zojk9N4bu-Z4ZnnHvaAGEKMxaTW6w2mzwWUhWyR29B1-haX2B0OR2OtiGZ4aww+74-zfPF8X2mWu5X8Cur4wFD9ANMVhL9u2rWt602JxB2HUcnCjUAwJ-LcoKcA96wQ6Re1AMIO3LH802jPN8O-Ksc2I+1SPAwsLx4ZcyDXDcqD-ODfTBIUYXEJizyoVCSGg2DrwQy4eM3SCBPQw8sJwvCT2YoiSPk3iKKU09aVotSFIAFko0Bo2UjSAFY6KAA)

---

So first we're producing union of tuple indexes using [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as). We're adding one more member to it (`[null, ...T]`) and then dropping zero index (`N extends "0"`) to start from `1`.

Next we use [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) with [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to produce the desired union.

```
Value extends string ? `${Prefix}-${Value}` : never
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-evil solution, we can use a helper type which converts a tuple like `[string, string, string]` into a union like `1 | 2 | 3`. This can be done recursively, using the `length` property of the tuple.

```
type TupleToUnion<T extends any[]> =
    T extends [any, ...infer R] ? T['length'] | TupleToUnion<R> : never

type GenerateUnion<T extends {name: string, colors: string[]}> =
    `${T['name']}-${TupleToUnion<T['colors']>}`

// 'default-3' | 'default-2' | 'default-1'
type DefaultColor = GenerateUnion<DefaultTheme>

// 'custom-5' | 'custom-4' | 'custom-3' | 'custom-2' | 'custom-1'
type CustomColor = GenerateUnion<CustomTheme>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-S7tRBdeQgA)